Given the following image, I am not sure how we get the equation$ \Delta s = \Delta x \sin(\theta)$
This image was taken from the text book "Introduction to Seismology." The question explores the use of Snell's law with wave fronts. Given the following geometry, I am not sure how the angle of \theta gives the equation
$$\Delta s = \Delta x \sin(\theta)$$


It is basic trigonometry, applied to a triangle where $\Delta x$ is the long side and $\Delta s$ one of the short sides, and $\theta$ or $90 - \theta$ the two relevant angles.

In the domain of seismology, proofs can be a little shaky.

@JeanMarie I can't tell if this pun was intentional, but it's amazing

I hope this diagram clears it.


Yes, that is very clear. Thank you for your help!

Construction of parallel and perpendicular lines is made as the following, and now find similar triangles from right triangle at left top.

